# Phase accumulation in Rabi driving

Tags: quantum-spin, hamiltonian, quantum-computer, rabi-model

When a single-qubit gate is operated by Rabi driving for a time $t$, the resulting operator is equivalent to
$ \hat{O} = R_z(\omega t) R_x(\Omega t)$
where $\omega$ is the frequency of the driving field, $\Omega$ is the Rabi frequency, and the phase of the driving field is assumed to be $\delta = 0$. Thus, after the pulse, the qubit state will have rotated by an angle $\theta = \Omega t$ around the $x$ axis, but also of an angle $\phi = \omega t$ around the $z$ axis. This is not a problem if only a single gate has to be applied, because the probability amplitudes for the $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states will be unaffected by this last rotation.

However, if more than one gate has to be applied to the same qubit, these $z$-phases would accumulate and can completely change the operation of the circuit. Suppose $t_1 = \pi /\Omega$, and we wish to apply a rotation $R_x(2\pi)$ using two Rabi driving pulses. Then after two $t_1$ pulses the equivalent operator will be given by:
\begin{equation}
\hat{O} = R_z(\omega t_1)R_x(\pi)R_z(\omega t_1)R_x(\pi)
\end{equation}
which however (in general) is completely different from:
\begin{equation}
\hat{O} = R_x(2\pi) = \hat{I}
\end{equation}

To get rid of the spurious phase, I would guess one should either add a forced $R_z(-\omega t_1)$ rotation in between the pulses, or wait for the qubit to "resynchronize" while precessing freely. However, none of the papers I've read mentions this issue. What am I missing?